# Считывание пробела

Tags: c++

Добрый день. Изучаю инструкцию SWITCH. Возникла проблема, не могу заставить компилятор считывать пробел?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char ab;
    std::cin >> ab;

    switch(ab)
    {
    case ' ':
        std::cout<<"space"<<std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout<<"Error"<<std::endl;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Для считывания отдельного символа лучше использовать функцию `get`:

```
cin.get(ab);
```

Просто `cin>>` пропускает пробельные символы, считая их несущественными :)

И еще... *Реальное* считывание произойдет после ввода . Ввод *буферизуется*, т.е. реальное размещение символа в `ab` будет после ввода всей строки, после чего в буфере останется, кстати, '\n'... Но для вашего примера это пока не важно.